# LDAP query cannot find a specific group in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have a macro within Excel that I periodically use to pull out details of group members within Active Directory.  It works fine for every group I've tried but I've come across one group that I just do not seem able to get data for.

The relevant bit of the script is below:

```
Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://[MyDomain.co.uk]/RootDSE")
DomainContainer = rootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "ADSDSOObject"
conn.Open "ADs Provider"


Set command = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set command.ActiveConnection = conn
command.Properties("Page size") = 200

groupDistinguisedName = "CN=[Group Name],OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=MyDomain,DC=co,DC=uk"
command.CommandText = "<LDAP://" & DomainContainer & ">;(distinguishedName=" & groupDistinguisedName & ");member;subtree"

Set rs = command.Execute

On Error Resume Next
dataVal = rs.Fields("member").Value
```

I've tried to run the script with a group name that does NOT exist and the script behaves in a different way - dataVal is set to **Empty** if the group does not exist, but is set to **Null** for the group I am having problems with, so it would appear that it has found the group but just somehow cannot get the members of the group.

I've tried cutting and pasting the distinguished name directly from Active Directory into the LDAP command string so I know it's not a typo on the name.  This group is a large group with lots of members but I've tried other large groups too.  I just can't see what could be causing the problem.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "member" attribute does not include members for primary group membership.
e.g. The "Domain Users" group may have many members but its "member" attribute can be empty.

To check primary group membership, please make use of the primaryGroupToken (group) and the primaryGroupId (user) attribute.

- Get the value of primaryGroupToken attribute from group
  (Note that primaryGroupToken is an constructed attribute)
- Search in the **SAME DOMAIN** for all users that has the same value in primaryGroupId

e.g. "Domain Users" group has a value of 513 in primaryGroupToken.
That means any user objects in the **same domain** whose primaryGroupId=513 are members of this "Domain Users" group.

Other comments:

- You already know the DN and the server. Why not directly call `GetObject("LDAP://[MyDomain.co.uk]/" & groupDistinguisedName)` to get the group?
  distinguishedName attribute is not indexed. The query can be slow in large env.
- If there are >1500 (configurable) members in "member" attribute, you need to use range retrieval. Otherwise you only get 1500.

Comment: My VBScript is not that good so the macro that I use is something cobbled together from various sources over the years.  The primaryGroupToken attribute token is not useful in my case as I need to be able to enumerate the members of any group not just the primary group.  I would like to see how to use GetObject as suggested if you could provide a bit more detail for me (although performance hasn't really been an issue so far).  The range retrieval is exactly the problem that I was having - the *members* attribute was null because there were more than 1500 members.  Thankyou!

Comment: Please check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746518(v=vs.85).aspx) for how to do Range Retrieval in VB.

Comment: Also, in theory, to show all the group members you will need to check both primary group and "normal" group membership. That means you cannot get the primary group members from "member" attribute, or vice versa. But in most cases, only a few special group (like Domain Users) have primary group member. You may handle both or omit primary group membership based on your use case.